# How to update/modify an existing entity (stored as JSON object on google app engine) through android app

Tags: android, json, google-app-engine, http, entity

I have created an Android app that stores certain information on a Google App Engine. Right now, I can only add information to the GAE using HTTP Post. But if I want to update a property of a value in my entity through the Android app, how would I update the values on the server? I can't figure out how to do that.
(If this is vague, ask me to post more about it).

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you mean datastore not google app engine and you use auto created endpoints, if that's the case it's pretty straight forward, you can use the auto created updateobject method. See below for an example. This is an auto created endpoint as well.

If I got it wrong, please explain the problem a little bit more and maybe include some part of your code

@ApiMethod(name = "updateUser",path="updateUser")

```
public User updateUser(User user) {
    PersistenceManager mgr = getPersistenceManager();
    try {
        if (!containsUser(user)) {
            throw new EntityNotFoundException("Object does not exist");
        }
        mgr.makePersistent(user);
    } finally {
        mgr.close();
    }
    return user;
}
```

Comment: So I have two projects in eclipse: one is an android app, and the other is a web applications that uses google app engine. The web project has some servlet files that have methods like "createorupdateentity" etc. And those are the methods I want to access from the Android app project, but I can't do that. I don't know how endpoints will affect my current projects so I have not looked into that. Is there any way for me to just update entities on the datastore through the android app by making calls to some methods in the servlet files?

Comment: Like my Web Application Project has:  private static DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
How can I access this variable from my Android application so that I can update existing data on the server?

Comment: i would advise you to use jdo to interact with datastore which is an easier way. Honestly, i do not use low level api in for datastore interaction. You can check : https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/overview-dn2